# Webdriver (Java) - [ChromeDriver: chrome on XP] print issue

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using following versions:

- TestNG 6.11.0
- ChromeDriver 2.38.552522
- Windows 7

My script prints the path of `findelement` intead of values belonging to the related `element`. Not sure if the paths defined in `findelement` is the root cause or the new version of `ChromeDriver`. I get following in the console upon running the test script:

```
[[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (8d6e0228a90daac67d21f6c2ff1c0ef3)] -> xpath: html/body/max-app-root/max-explore/div[2]/div[1]/p]
[[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (8d6e0228a90daac67d21f6c2ff1c0ef3)] -> class name: ng-star-inserted]
[[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (8d6e0228a90daac67d21f6c2ff1c0ef3)] -> class name: card-price]
[[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (8d6e0228a90daac67d21f6c2ff1c0ef3)] -> class name: card-subtitle]
[[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (8d6e0228a90daac67d21f6c2ff1c0ef3)] -> class name: explore-mi]
[[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (8d6e0228a90daac67d21f6c2ff1c0ef3)] -> xpath: html/body/max-app-root/max-explore/max-campaign-information/div/aside/div[1]/div[1]/h4]
[[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (8d6e0228a90daac67d21f6c2ff1c0ef3)] -> xpath: html/body/max-app-root/max-explore/max-campaign-information/div/aside/div[1]/div[2]/h4]
[[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (8d6e0228a90daac67d21f6c2ff1c0ef3)] -> xpath: html/body/max-app-root/max-explore/max-campaign-information/div/aside/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/p]
[[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (8d6e0228a90daac67d21f6c2ff1c0ef3)] -> xpath: html/body/max-app-root/max-explore/max-campaign-information/div/aside/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/p]
[[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (8d6e0228a90daac67d21f6c2ff1c0ef3)] -> xpath: html/body/max-app-root/max-explore/max-campaign-information/div/aside/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/p]
[[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (8d6e0228a90daac67d21f6c2ff1c0ef3)] -> xpath: html/body/max-app-root/max-explore/max-campaign-information/div/aside/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/p]
[[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (8d6e0228a90daac67d21f6c2ff1c0ef3)] -> xpath: html/body/max-app-root/max-explore/max-campaign-information/div/aside/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/p]
[[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (8d6e0228a90daac67d21f6c2ff1c0ef3)] -> xpath: html/body/max-app-root/max-explore/max-campaign-information/div/aside/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[1]/h4]
[[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (8d6e0228a90daac67d21f6c2ff1c0ef3)] -> xpath: html/body/max-app-root/max-explore/max-campaign-information/div/aside/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/p]
```

My script is as mentioned below:

`

```
@Test(priority = 13)

public void Explore_check_input_in_feedback () throws InterruptedException

{

WebElement CampaignName = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/max-app-root/max-explore/max-campaign-information/div/aside/div[1]/div[1]/h4"));

WebElement NowPay = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/max-app-root/max-explore/max-campaign-information/div/aside/div[1]/div[2]/h4"));

WebElement StartDate = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/max-app-root/max-explore/max-campaign-information/div/aside/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/p"));

WebElement EndDate = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/max-app-root/max-explore/max-campaign-information/div/aside/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/p"));

WebElement Estimations = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/max-app-root/max-explore/max-campaign-information/div/aside/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/p"));

WebElement Budget = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/max-app-root/max-explore/max-campaign-information/div/aside/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/p"));

WebElement BusinessOutcome = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/max-app-root/max-explore/max-campaign-information/div/aside/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/p"));

WebElement TotalCost = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/max-app-root/max-explore/max-campaign-information/div/aside/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[1]/h4"))    WebElement Savings = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/max-app-root/max-explore/max-campaign-information/div/aside/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[2]/p"));

    CampaignName.getSize();
    Assert.assertTrue(CampaignName != null);
    System.out.println(CampaignName);

    NowPay.getSize();
    Assert.assertTrue(NowPay != null);
    System.out.println(NowPay);

    StartDate.getSize();
    Assert.assertTrue(StartDate != null);
    System.out.println(StartDate);

    EndDate.getSize();
    Assert.assertTrue(EndDate != null);
    System.out.println(EndDate);

    Estimations.getSize();
    Assert.assertTrue(Estimations != null);
    System.out.println(Estimations);

    Budget.getSize();
    Assert.assertTrue(Budget != null);
    System.out.println(Budget);

    BusinessOutcome.getSize();
    Assert.assertTrue(BusinessOutcome != null);
    System.out.println(BusinessOutcome);

    TotalCost.getSize();
    Assert.assertTrue(TotalCost != null);
    System.out.println(TotalCost);

    Savings.getSize();
    Assert.assertTrue(Savings != null);
    System.out.println(Savings);
    }`
```

Comment: show your script code as well.

Comment: Its a huge code, just copying a part of it which is creating problem. Please refer the question again. I've updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I updated the `ChromeDriver`, for printing I have to clearly define it.
Example; If a WebElement `Error` is defined in the script and I write `System.out.println(Error)`, it'll print the `path` of the element. I have to mention `System.out.println(Error).getText()` instead to print the actual value.